# Does the 'sysrq' key have any function in Windows?

Tags: windows, sysrq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the SysRq key do?](https://superuser.com/questions/4461/what-does-the-sysrq-key-do)

Does the <kbd>SYSRQ</kbd> key have any function in Windows?
I know it is used in Linux to pass commands directly to the kernel, and in old OSs for similar tasks, but is it used in modern versions of Windows?

An answer to a similar question [What does the SysRq key do?](https://superuser.com/questions/4461/what-does-the-sysrq-key-do) mentioned that it was "a programmable key", so is reprogramming that key builtin functionality for Windows, or is a 3rd party program necessary?

**EDIT:** Not a duplicate; I am asking for more information about other possible uses for the key (such as remapping)

Comment: It's for taking screenshots! ;)

Comment: I think they closed it because the Wikipedia page does mention a use in Windows ([debugging in NT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_request#Other_uses)). Also, since the `SysReq` key is technically just `Alt+PrtScr`, Windows *does* use it to capture just the active window. As for programming/remapping, you *can* remap it, but you need to remap `Alt+PrtScr` (just like you cannot remap `@` since it is not a separate key; you remap `Shift+2` instead).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

nothing standard in windows and newer keyboards do not even have that key (some have alt-scrLk for sysrq), though used for debugging in some windows versions. see the wiki article here for details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_request

Comment: I've never seen a full-sized PC keyboard which lacked the SysRq key.

Comment: The one I am using is fullsize from MicroSoft and it does not have this key, at least not labeled as such.

Comment: No doubt there are keyboards, many of them, without the key. But they aren't in danger of outnumbering those that do any time soon.

Comment: I have a full-sized Logitech keyboard in front of me without a SysRq key.  (It's Alt+PrintScrn I believe, which isn't that unusual for 101-key keyboards honestly)

Comment: I believe SysRq has **always** been alt-prtscr.  Like Break.

Comment: @surfasb - No, old-school 84-key layouts had it on a dedicated key.  (I don't remember very well but I think it was on the top-right corner of the 10-key pad?)

Comment: *> I believe SysRq has always been alt-prtscr. Like Break.*   I assume you mean *like Break is `Ctrl+Pause`*.     *> No, old-school 84-key layouts had it on a dedicated key.*   This question is about (modern) Windows. (Technically I suppose it could be possible for an old keyboard’s controller to send the scancode for the `SysReq` key to a current version of Windows, but then who has a Windows 7 system with a 5-pin AT keyboard?)